# Product image is not getting uploaded

Tags: image, magento, product, uploading

- I am trying to upload a product image from images tab in the manage product link.

  - When i click on the browse file button i am able to see image which i ready to upload and i am able to upload by clicking on the upload button.
  - But when i browse the button on the mac and in all browsers after that browser image is not showing and i am not able to upload.
  - In windows and unix in all browsers it is working fine.but not in the mac.

Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this question doesn't appear to have *anything* to do with programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be because of the flash.  Magento admin used flash plugin to upload the images.  Please install the flash plugin or update the Safari.

Comment: thanks for quick reply.the issues is on the all broswers on the mac.